# HTML & CSS Icons no showing

Tags: html, css

So im using some icons for social links and there not showing up, I know i have the right file paths and etc.

Could some one take alook at the code and help me out please? Thanks In advance

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.icon-cube {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
          perspective: 800px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.icon-cube::before,
.icon-cube::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../img/icons5.png");
  background-image: url("../img/icons5.svg"), none;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
}

.icon-cube::before {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #595959;
}

.icon-cube::after {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(48px) rotateX(-90deg);
          transform: translateY(48px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.icon-cube:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-48px) rotateX(90deg);
          transform: translateY(-48px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.icon-cube:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
          transform: rotateX(0);
}

/* facebook */
.icon-cube.facebook::before,
.icon-cube.facebook::after {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.icon-cube.facebook::after {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

/* twitter */
.icon-cube.twitter::before,
.icon-cube.twitter::after {
  background-position: -96px 0;
}

.icon-cube.twitter::after {
  background-color: #4099ff;
}

/* google plus */
.icon-cube.googleplus::before,
.icon-cube.googleplus::after {
  background-position: -192px 0;
}

.icon-cube.googleplus::after {
  background-color: #d34836;
}

/* github */
.icon-cube.github::before,
.icon-cube.github::after {
  background-position: -288px 0;
}

.icon-cube.github::after {
  background-color: #333333;
}

/* rss */
.icon-cube.rss::before,
.icon-cube.rss::after {
  background-position: -384px 0;
}

.icon-cube.rss::after {
  background-color: #ee802f;
}
```

```html
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 social-link">
                        <p spellcheck="true">
                        <ul class="social">
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE facebook">facebook</a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE twitter">twitter</a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE googleplus">google+</a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE github">github</a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE rss">rss</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; TomTucka 2015</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Again Thanks in advance, First code set is CSS and Second HTML

Comment: So you've inspected the images with your browser and it shows you no errors with the path? Because 99% of the time that's the problem. Also note that your CSS references `icon-cube` which doesn't exist in the HTML you posted.

Comment: You never use `.icon-cube` in your html, so why should the styles you defined for that get applied? Instead you have `icon-TYPE` class on your icons and that does never show up in your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is missing the `.icon-cube` class

Answer (score 0):

Ah so I forgot to re-name my class new HTML looks like the snippet below and it works, Thanks for the help should probably take a break for abit!!

```
    <footer>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 social-link">
                    <p spellcheck="true">
                    <ul class="icon-cube">
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE facebook">facebook</a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE twitter">twitter</a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE googleplus">google+</a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE github">github</a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-TYPE rss">rss</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; TomTucka 2015</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```